# CMFCToolBarComboBoxEdit handle delete button

Tags: c++, mfc

`CMFCToolBarComboBoxEdit` handles the BackSpace button but it doesn't handle the delete button.
Is there any way to handle the delete button except `PreTranslateMessage`?
if yes, what is this way?
if no, then how can I get the current cursor position in the control and how to remove specific char using its index so I can remove the char which on the right of the cursor if nothing is selected?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use, `PreTranslateMessage`. If you detected the sequence that should be handled, call:

```
if (..) // Check if you have a message that should 
        // be passed to the window directly
{
  TranslateMessage(pMsg);
  DispatchMessage(pMsg);
  return TRUE;
}
```

You can do this always in `PreTranslateMessage`, when you detect that the message should be handled by the default control, and should not be handled by any other control in the chain of windows that execute `PreTranslateMessage`. This is also helpful if you have a combo box open and want the Page Down/Up handled internally and not by the view or any accelerator.

Answer (score 0):

I've handled the delete key in the `PreTranslateMessage` as follows:

```
BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
  if(WM_KEYDOWN == pMsg->message && VK_DELETE == pMsg->wParam)
  {
    int iStartChar = -1, iEndChar = -1;
    GetSel(iStartChar, iEndChar);
    if(iStartChar != iEndChar)
      Clear(); //clear the selected text
    else
    {
      SetSel(iStartChar, iStartChar + 1);
      Clear();
    }
  }

  return CMFCToolBarComboBoxEdit::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```